Convert the MongoDB query to Opensearch
I have the aggregation query in mongoDB which is working properly. THis query finds the count of the users hour-wise but only consider the first arrival of the user. For example if user arrives at 11 AM and then again at 2 PM, then count will be 1 for this user at 11 AM and that's it. If the same user comes again then count should not be calculated. for simplicity we can say hour-wise count of the first arrival of the user.
This is the mongoDB query, I am using the variables as it is form the mongoDB code

aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    sequr_code: { $in: sequr_code },
                    'actor.user.uuid': { $in: valid_users },
                    time: { $gt: start_date, $lte: end_date },
                    'location.uuid': location_id,
                },
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    time: 1,
                },
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        uuid: '$actor.user.uuid',
                    },
                    tran: { $first: '$$ROOT' },
                },
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        hour: { $hour: { date: '$tran.time', timezone: location_tz } },
                        minute: {
                            $subtract: [
                                { $minute: { date: '$tran.time', timezone: location_tz } },
                                { $mod: [{ $minute: '$tran.time' }, 60] },
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                    count: { $addToSet: '$tran.actor.user.uuid' },
                },
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    interv_start: { $add: ['$_id.hour', 0] },
                    interv_end: { $add: ['$_id.hour', 1] },
                    total_user_arrivals: { $size: '$count' },
                    _id: 0,
                    uuid: '$_id.uuid',
                },
            },
        ])


Can anyone help me to convert this query to opensearch. I have tried a lot but it didn't work out. Thanks
I am expecting the count of the users hour-wise like count at 12 AM, 1 AM, ...... 5 PM....11 PM, but as I mentioned any hour should not contain the count of the same user, one user can only be considered once and that too the first arrival.
This is the sample data
This is the sample data
{
  "actor": {
    "user": {
      "role": "ADMIN",
      "cost_center": null,
      "name": "Lauren Stephens",
      "access_groups": [],
      "employee_number": null,
      "department": null,
      "uuid": "06fa0334-6ad1-48db-af97-18410496685d",
      "email": "lauren.stephens@example.com"
    }
  },
  "location": {
    "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
    "name": "Ahmedabad",
    "uuid": "88daf957-cda2-45b2-b008-ff65b299cadc"
  },
  "time": "2024-04-30T23:30:00.000Z",
  "tenant": {
    "name": "Swiggy",
    "uuid": "917d3da4-705e-49b4-8d05-9d8d405db6e2"
  }
}




If you can post a sample data, it will be helpful. At a first glance, it looks like you may need a scripted aggregation. https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/aggregations/metric/scripted-metric/

I have updated the the question with the sample data, you can take a reference from that
